# django display uploaded by user images

Tags: django

I have ImageUploadField
I save images at `my_project/forum_attachments` directory.

But when I try to display them and see by this link: http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum_attachments/1466786056166112161_Nrns2WL.jpg
I get an error

> Page not found (404) Request Method:  GET Request
>   URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/forum_attachments/1466786056166112161_Nrns2WL.jpg

What do I do?

UPD: `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('some_app.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),

    url(r'^user_logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^index_old/', views.index_old, name='index_old'),
    url(r'^forum/', views.forum, name='forum'),
    url(r'^vip/', views.vip, name='vip'),
    url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),
    url(r'^forum_new/', views.forum_new, name='forum_new'),
]
```

Comment: You need to access it by using `MEDIA_URL` prefix. What is the `MEDIA_URL` you have set in `settings.py`? and how you are displaying in template?

Comment: @AamirAdnan  I tried: `MEDIA_URL = '../forum_attachments/'`  and MEDIA_URL = '/forum_attachments/'

Comment: Show me your main `urls.py` file, are you handling serving of media files? and `MEDIA_URL` need to be `/forum_attachments/` in your case.

Comment: @AamirAdnan see update

Answer (score 0):

First set in `settings.py`:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/forum_attachments/'
```

Then in your main `urls.py` add following piece of code:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you've not set your MEDIA_URL & MEDIA ROOT in settings or your local settings file, you should follow the below procedure.

Settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'../media/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Now in your Urls.py, do this:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('some_app.urls')),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^about/', views.about, name='about'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),

    url(r'^user_logout/$', views.user_logout, name='user_logout'),
    url(r'^index_old/', views.index_old, name='index_old'),
    url(r'^forum/', views.forum, name='forum'),
    url(r'^vip/', views.vip, name='vip'),
    url(r'^test/', views.test, name='test'),
    url(r'^forum_new/', views.forum_new, name='forum_new'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The 'static' was appended to the urlpatterns because your DEBUG might be set to True in your settings.py.

Comment: how does this connected with my `forum_attachments` directory?

Comment: If your media files are in 'forum_attachments' instead of 'media' folder, replace the media with 'forum_attachments'. It will be MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'../forum_attachments/'), MEDIA_URL = '/forum_attachments/'